# Can I set user group attributes in the concrete5.6 dashboard?

Tags: concrete5

I need to specify attributes for some users depending on the group they belong to. So, instead of repeating attribute values in every user attribute I would like to assign those attributes to the user group but I can't see how to do it through the dashboard or the API. Is this possible?

Thanks